# Why am I not able to display this specific # variable value?

Tags: c#, .net, webforms, user-controls, eval

This is my `runat="server"` html element:

```
<a runat="server" href='<%#link%>' ID="TheLink">
    Test
</a>
```

and I need to print inside the `href` the value of the `link` variable (defined on the .cs):

```
protected string link = "http://www.test.com";
```

but I'm not able: the variable value is "empty". Where am I wrong?

The same if I use native `HyperLink` control...

Answer (score 0):

I think you may change this

`<a runat="server" href='<%#link%>' ID="TheLink">
    Test
</a>`

To this

`<a href='<%=link%>' ID="TheLink">
    Test
</a>`

`<%#` just runs code, but doesn't output anything. `<%=` will output whatever is inside those tags.

Don't forget to remove `runat=server` since `<%=` will generate as plain text if you don't remove it.

OR Maybe you can change to this

```
<asp:LinkButton id="myid" runat="server" OnClick="redirectToLink" Text="Test" />
```

behind code:

```
protected string link = "http://www.test.com";
protected void redirectToLink(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect(link);
        }
```

OR if you insist to use href with code behind, you can do this:

```
<asp:Label ID="testLabel" runat="server" />
```

code behind:

```
protected string link = "http://www.test.com";
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                testLabel.Text = string.Format("You also have to click on is <a href=\"{0}\"> link </a>",link);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You can't use `=` into a runat="server" type.

Comment: I can't and I don't want to remove runat=server. I need it .)

Comment: I've edited my answer, You can choose which one do you think you can and do it.

Comment: No one reply to my answer of "why I can't use" variable inside that element :(

Comment: does it help to make the variable public?

Comment: @markzzz : I think I mentioned it before `<%# just runs code, but doesn't output anything. <%= will output whatever is inside those tags.`